# Currency: Display price on products in USD but only use EUR for invoices. Magento 1.9 german

Tags: price, ce-1.9.0.1, invoice, currency, multicurrency

I'm using Magento 1.9 customized german version.

Is it possible to set it so all prices are displayed in USD only.
That means even after putting products in your shopping basket and going through the whole payment procedure everything is displayed in USD. The customer also pays for their purchase in USD too.
But the invoice should only be in EUR (Price should already/automatically converted from USD into EUR).

I hope that you guys could understand what im looking for.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes, understood, and no. Magento works in the base currency, you would need to do some fancy coding to adjust the invoice - seems a bit weird. Have you tested this with customers, normally they don't like checkouts in non-local currency.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System - Configuration - Currency setup and change what you need there. You might need to do that in the store views if you have them or make it a website configuration.

[image]

And in allowed currencies add any currency you want to support (i suspect it is only USD).

Also remember to add the currency exchange rate in System - Manage currencies - Rates.